# How do I get columns from a joined table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, join

For a single table, I normally do something like this:

```
$length = 42;
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM table WHERE length = "' . $length . '"', $dbconn);
$rowsfound = mysql_num_rows ($result);
if ($rowsfound == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    $tableid = $row ['table_id'];
    $tablecloth = $row ['tablecloth'];
    $height = $row ['height'];
    ...
```

But how to I get the rows from a joined table like this:

```
$chairid = 123;
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM table,chair WHERE chair.id = "' . $chairid . '" AND table.table_id = chair.table_id', $dbconn);
$rowsfound = mysql_num_rows ($result);
if ($rowsfound == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    $tableid = $row ['table.table_id'];
    $tablecloth = $row ['table.tablecloth'];
    $height = $row ['table.height'];
    ...
```

This doesn't return any values in $table.tablecloth.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a closing parenthesis after every `$row` value? - `$row ['']);`

Comment: Also, you don't need to use the table name - `$tableid = $row ['table_id'];` / `$tablecloth = $row ['tablecloth'];` / `$height = $row ['height'];` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this with JOIN instead

```
    SELECT * FROM table
    INNER JOIN chair  ON table.table_id = chair.table_id 
    WHERE chair.id = "' . $chairid . '"
```

Comment: This is the most elegant of the three answers that exist at this moment.  I tried it and it worked, so this is the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting any results is because your query is failing.  `table` is a reserved word so you need to add back ticks around it as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM `table`,`chair` WHERE `chair`.id = "' . $chairid . '" AND `table`.table_id = `chair`.table_id', $dbconn);
```

You would had figured this out if you had proper error handling in place like following (note the `or die()`:

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM `table`,`chair` WHERE `chair`.id = "' . $chairid . '" AND `table`.table_id = `chair`.table_id', $dbconn) or die(mysql_error())
```

Please refer to the list of reserved words here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Apart from this, as Kim pointed out you also need to fix the extra closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better doing a proper JOIN like echo_Me suggested but this is the proper syntax for the way you are coding it.

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT table.*,chair.* FROM table,chair WHERE chair.id = "' . $chairid . '" AND table.table_id = chair.table_id', $dbconn);
```

Then

```
if ($rowsfound == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    $tableid    = $row ['table_id'];
    $tablecloth = $row ['tablecloth'];
    $height     = $row ['height'];
```

The results do not get returned with the table name in front of the column names. This can cause a problem if you have a column name with the same name in both tables.

Comment: Yeah, after I asked the question, I realized my biggest problem (aside from the unbalanced paren and using reserved words in my example) was my names were ambiguous.  Explicitly naming the columns instead of * and using AS to reassign the qualified column names to unique names was one option, but clumsy.  Doing an INNER JOIN as echo_Me suggested worked perfectly and is cleaner looking code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have extra closing parenthesis?? )

> ```
> $tableid = $row ['table.table_id']);
> $tablecloth = $row ['table.tablecloth']);
> $height = $row ['table.height']);
> ```